# Selection for batch operation in Gmail's new material design

Tags: gmail, user-interface, material-design

I'm confused, while I'm trying to understand the new Gmail "compact" style user interface. This is the view, where left to the email's 2-line representation a checkbox can be found.  I can't really grasp the UI presentation of "selection". Please, take a look at these four screenshots.

1. **Selected and checked**

   > [image: selected and checked]
2. **Selected but unchecked**

   > [image: selected but unchecked]
3. **Checked but unselected?**

   > [image: checked but unselected?]
4. **Selected and unchecked, but different from (2)**

   > [image: selected, unchecked but different from 2]

It is clear (from the operation appearing at the upper part of the screen), that 1, 2 and 4 are selections. Why is the UI different in these cases? Also clear, that 3 is **not** selection... but a checkbox has a mark in it, and it normally *used to* mean selection for further operation.

So I'm totally confused, what the UI tries to tell me. Could you please shed some light on what

- checkbox (marked and unmarked state)
- colored background
- thick, and thin frame of the checkbox

mean in the context of email selection?